# MySQL replication: Prevent a specific procedure call on slave

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, replication

I have one master and 2 slaves and have replication set at statement level.
I want to purge records older than specific date on master and one of the slave. I created a procedure to do that.
Is there any way I can skip procedure call on 2nd slave and execute that on 1st slave?

Please note that I want to execute all other statements and I want to schedule purge procedure call as MySQL event.

Thanks and best regards,
Santosh!

Answer (score 0):

Declare the procedure to some sort of No-Op on the 2nd slave. The statement will still get sent and processed but won't do anything.